# Removing negative strings using RegEx

Tags: regex, vba

I need RegEx code to match only negative string using below patterns.

### Input:

### `a+e+-b+-c+-g+-k+-j+-n;`

### Expected output after applying RegEx

### `a+e;`

### Input:

### `(g/k)+-a+-(g+h)+-j+-n;`

### Expected output after applying RegEx

### `(g/k);`

### Input:

### `n+k+-a+-g+-j/n+-a+-g+-k+-j;`

### Expected output after applying RegEx

### `n+k/n;`

### Input:

### `-a+-b;`

### Expected output after applying RegEx

### `;`

### Input:

### `-(a+b)+-c;`

### Expected output after applying RegEx

`;`

Currently i am writing VBA code to process for each type of string. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Please include your pattern that failed in question.

Comment: Where did these strings come from? Would it be simpler to fix the issue at the source? Also, is this a one-time task?

Comment: @bobblebubble: i have given differnt type string pattern as input i he question. Currently i have not written any RegEx as i m using VBA. In VBA, i split each string using "+-" and replace each element in the array with null

Comment: @ashleedawg : it is tough to do anything with the source as i dont have control.

Comment: Probably could use something like [`[+*\/-]*-(?:\([^)]*\)|\w+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%2b*%5c%2f-%5d*-%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5b%5e%29%5d*%5c%29%7c%5cw%2b%29&i=a%2be%2b-b%2b-c%2b-g%2b-k%2b-j%2b-n%3b%0d%0a%28g%2fk%29%2b-a%2b-%28g%2bh%29%2b-j%2b-n%3b%0d%0an%2bk%2b-a%2b-g%2b-j%2fn%2b-a%2b-g%2b-k%2b-j%3b%0d%0a-a%2b-b%3b%0d%0a-%28a%2bb%29%2b-c%3b%0d%0a) (depends on exact requirements).

Comment: Great @bobblebubble it works as of now for the given pattern. I will check with the original source and mark as answer here. Thanks for your quick support.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Could you please help me in correcting the RegEX for -a+b/-c+d as input? Currently it gives output as +b+d but i want output as +b/+d. It is missing the "/" sign. For all other cases given RegEx works perfectly.

Comment: @Suresh you can modify the regex to your needs, try [`[+-]*-(?:\([^)]*\)|\w+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%2b-%5d*-%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5b%5e%29%5d*%5c%29%7c%5cw%2b%29&i=a%2be%2b-b%2b-c%2b-g%2b-k%2b-j%2b-n%3b%0d%0a%28g%2fk%29%2b-a%2b-%28g%2bh%29%2b-j%2b-n%3b%0d%0an%2bk%2b-a%2b-g%2b-j%2fn%2b-a%2b-g%2b-k%2b-j%3b%0d%0a-a%2b-b%3b%0d%0a-%28a%2bb%29%2b-c%3b%0d%0a-a%2bb%2f-c%2bd&r=) (now it leaves `/` or `*` before the `-` but would remove any `+-` if before. To only remove plusses before `-`, use `\+*-(?:\([^)]*\)|\w+)` or if max one plus before minus, use `\+?-(?:\([^)]*\)|\w+)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @bobblebubble

Comment: you're welcome @Suresh